# Adding an Excel file in PBI report

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerbi

I've created a report from a database in power bi report server but while creating the report, I have added one Excel file to my report and when I want to upload my report on the power bi server, I receive a massage, telling that the Excel file cannot be identified.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Power BI service cannot connect to your Excel file.

A couple of possible solutions:

1. Save the Excel file to the cloud (e.g. OneDrive or SharePoint) and point your Power BI file at the cloud copy instead of your local copy.
2. Set up a [data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-onprem) so that the Service can connect to your local file.

The second option is a lot more work.